# align-items : what is the difference between flex-start and Stretch?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

can you please tell me align-items : what is the difference between flex-start and Stretch?

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end
}

.container .box {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://cssreference.io/flexbox/#align-items

Comment: they gave me the same result !

Comment: show us so we can see

Answer (score 2):

You will see no difference if you **set a height** to your element.

> stretch
>
> Flex items are stretched such that the cross-size of the item's margin box is the same as the line **while respecting width and height constraints.**<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)</sup>

In your case, nothing will happen with stretch because of the height you set.

> flex-start
>
> The cross-start margin edges of the flex items are flushed with the cross-start edge of the line. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)</sup>

This is simply align the item on the top. Again, nothing will happen visually since it's somehow the default behavior *(not the default value)*.

```css
.container {
  display:inline-flex;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:2px solid;
}

.container > span {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="align-items:flex-start">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="container" style="align-items:stretch">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Now remove the height constraint and you will see the difference:

```css
.container {
  display:inline-flex;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:2px solid;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.container > span {
  width:100px;
  min-height:100px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="align-items:flex-start">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="container" style="align-items:stretch">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: my quetion is why when a add a max-height to the container
it apear like this 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11MefzCvLzVqCZdMewEpbzVejTte_xZAi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @adamlolo we need to see code, edit your question with the code that reproduce this